# Is it possible to use display math mode in hidden text?

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown-preview

I sometimes like to use the ability to hide text when writing an answer, but I've noticed that when I try to write something in display math mode (i.e. maths wrapped in double dollar signs), it doesn't display as such but rather as regular maths mode (i.e. as if the maths was wrapped in single dollar signs). When I try to fix this, the text no longer remains hidden.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373246/39599) is what made me ask this question. If anyone knows a way around this, please let me know.

---

**Added later:** It appears that when the answer is submitted, the relevant math is displayed in display math mode, but in the writing (or editing) process, it is only displayed in regular math mode. Thanks to Martin for pointing this out. I have added the bug tag.

Comment: Well, the line starting with $f(b)$ is hidden, and shown in display math to me... Perhaps the issue is browser or MathJax renderer (MathML, HTML/CSS, SVG) related?

Comment: That's weird. It's working for me now as well, but wasn't at the time.

Comment: It's working for me. And the current browser I'm using is Firefox 20.0.1.

Comment: Looking at the preview when editing your answer, the equation in double dollars is rendered as if it were an inline equation [(screen shot)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RExzM.png). The posted version looks fine [(screen shot)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OCKBu.png). If that's what you experienced, maybe add a bug tag?

Comment: I retagged, as this seems to be a bug with the previewer not working the same as the final rendering.